# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column accounts_account.username does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I am getting this error after I was customizing my Customer User Model. and now I get this error when I try to login into the admin panel and when I try to create a superuser.

I tried to drop the postgresql database called skincareryland... but am getting an error on the password login... when I try to change the password I get this error.. ERROR:  role "postgres" does not exist

I also tried going through these steps from an overstack post, but not having any luck fixing the problem... Comment out 'django.contrib.admin' from INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py and comment out # path('admin/', admin.site.urls) in urls.py

[here is a better snapshot of my models.py code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJWBV.jpg)

[here is a better snapshot of my settings.py code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhSF3.jpg)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, 
BaseUserManager



class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
   def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, 
     password=None):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('User must have an email address')

    if not username:
        raise ValueError('User must have an username')

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        username=username,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, first_name, last_name, email, username, 
password):
    user = self.create_user(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        username=username,
        password=password,
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
    )
    user.is_admin = True
    user.is_active = True
    user.is_staff = True
    user.is_superadmin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user


    class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
       first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
       last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
       username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
       email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
       phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)

      # required
      date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      is_superadmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

     USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
     REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

     objects = MyAccountManager()

     def full_name(self):
       return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

    def __str__(self):
       return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
       return self.is_admin

   def has_module_perms(self, add_label):
       return True


class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   address_line_1 = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
   address_line_2 = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
   profile_picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, 
   upload_to='userprofile')
   city = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
   state = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
   country = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)


def __str__(self):
    return self.user.first_name

def full_address(self):
    return f'{self.address_line_1} {self.address_line_2}'
```

Here is my Traceback error:

[image: traceback]

Comment: Maybe you missed running a migration?  It seems like the database currently has `user_name` when you need it to have `username`.

Comment: I just ran python3 manage.py migrate and python3 manage.py makemigrations again and that's not it... but it is interested about the user_name cos I corrected that typo in models earlier, but it must be showing user_name somewhere in my code...

Comment: Examine the database directly and see what the column name is.  The error message seems to imply there's a `user_name` but no `username`.

Comment: BTW, you have a `username` but if you call `get_username()` on your object you'll get the `email` value because you set `USERNAME_FIELD` to be `email`.  You may want to re-examine that part.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your `settings.py` you need to add the line

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.Account'
```

or

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Account'
```

depending on how you set up the project.

Also remove all migrations and drop the database, then do them again.

Comment: your_app in this case is accounts...  so I had "AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.Account' and when I changed to "AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Account" just now on the recommendation, it gives me this error... django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL must be of the form 'app_label.model_name'

Comment: I'm trying to drop the database but my password is not being accepted... and when I type "python3 manage.py changepassword taniryla" it takes me to the error above... i tried typing "sudo -u taniryla psql skincareryland" to bypass the password to set a new one... but when I type in "sudo su postgres" the password I updated doesn't work and I get a "Sorry, try again" error message...

Comment: Ok, so you had `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Account'` which should be correct. As for the database problem, you will to fix it. In the meantime, to make sure your django code works, if you are in development you can either create a new postgresql database or use the default db.sqlite3 database for which no password is needed. Remember to empty all migrations folders (leaving only `__init__.py`)

Comment: so I wasn't able to access through "sudo -u taniryla psql skincareryland" but based on your insight above about "AUTH_USER_MODEL", I commented that out and now was able to do get "python3 manage.py flush" to erase all the data in the database... I also deleted the __pycache__ and migrations... when I try to run "python3 manage.py createsuperuser", it now gives me an ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject' error which I don't understand because I never named anything myproject.

Comment: that's a good idea... it's just in development mode and so I'll just create a new postgresql database... thanks for the suggestion, I'll try this..

Comment: so I created a new database after delete all the __pycache__ and migrations.... then set-up new migrations on the new database... however, when I try to create a superuser, it gives me this ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'... lol

Comment: unfortunately it is difficult to understand what the problem is not being able to look at all the code. While you are solving this problem, every time you make a change I recommend that you remove all migrations and database and recreate everything. Also, referring to the code you posted in your question, `def create_superuser` must be indented to belong to `class MyAccountManager`

Comment: thanks for your help... the def create_superuser is indented under class MyAccountManager... I created better code snapshots of settings.py and models.py above now in a photo link.... it was all working before I had the issues with the database sync

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

try to run this command