# After dropping database, I am getting this ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject' error

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models

I ran into a database out of sync error and so I dropped one database in development mode and synced my settings to a newly created postgresql database. I removed my **pycache** and migrations prior to creating a new database and then ran the "python3 manage.py makemigrations" and "python3 manage.py migrate".

Here is a link to the prior error and code if that's necessary to know.  [django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column accounts_account.username does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71018789/django-db-utils-programmingerror-column-accounts-account-username-does-not-exis)

However, when I ran "python3 manage.py createsuperuser" it gave me this ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject' error. I don't quite understand this error because I never named my project 'myproject'. Perhaps, I am not understanding something when dropping one database and setting up a new database.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/Users/taniryla/ecommerce/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/taniryla/ecommerce/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/skincareryland/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/skincareryland/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/skincareryland/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/skincareryland/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/skincareryland/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/skincareryland/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/Users/taniryla/ecommerce/accounts/models.py", line 27, in create_superuser
    user = self.create_user(
  File "/Users/taniryla/ecommerce/accounts/models.py", line 22, in create_user
    user.set_password(password)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/skincareryland/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 99, in set_password
    self.password = make_password(raw_password)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/skincareryland/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py", line 81, in make_password
    hasher = get_hasher(hasher)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/skincareryland/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py", line 122, in get_hasher
    return get_hashers()[0]
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/skincareryland/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py", line 90, in get_hashers
    hasher_cls = import_string(hasher_path)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/skincareryland/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/skincareryland/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'
```